# Open TortoiseSVN RepoBrowser from C# Code

Tags: c#, winforms, shell, tortoisesvn

I want to open TortoiseSVN Repo Browser in a specified "url/path" when i click in a button.

(Windows Forms/C#)

Thanks.

Comment: `Process.Start("svn://path/to/repo")` if it is a svn url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will use the Windows Shell to launch the EXE:

```
Process.Start(pathToFile);
```

Now, you'll probably also want to supply some arguments, so you can do that like this:

```
var info = new ProcessStartInfo(pathToFile, arguments);
Process.Start(info);
```

You'll need to set the arguments to a valid set of arguments for the command-line for that application.

Comment: Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("TortoiseProc.exe", "/command:repobrowser");
            p.Start();

Comment: @Rieth, yes that's another approach. Though not any better per say than the one I proposed. What are you trying to say?

Comment: But now how i put the url in the text box ?

Comment: @Rieth, what do you mean put the URL in the text box?

Comment: When i execute this process it open the RepoBrowser screen that asks for a url ... https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQLehCJ8xGN_0uWYMT7P-Dewh4aW5BPtGZeoOn28JfCYz8Xr56P

Comment: @Rieth, if that value can't be sent via the command-line you're going to be stuck with some *very nasty* Windows API's to get this done. That is far too broad for this forum.

Comment: @Reith - There's a /path parameter you can pass - see below.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the answer of Michael Perrenoud:

```
var info = new ProcessStartInfo("/PathToTortoise/TortoiseProc.exe", "/command:repobrowser /path:PathToRepository");
Process.Start(info);
```

/command:repobrowser tells tortoise to start the repobrowser.

/path tells the repobrowser which path to open.

Answer (score 2):

The command you would need to run at the command line is something like:

```
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe /command:repobrowser /path:"myPath"
```

In C# you could start this like this:

```
String path = "myPath";
Process.Start("TortoiseProc.exe", 
        String.Format("/command:repobrowser /path:\"{0}\"", path));
```

All the documentation for automating TSVN is here:

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html

Comment: +1 for the documentation on how to get that path in there for the OP!